# Dot notation for class member access

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got the following code:

```
public class Random
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsRunning()
    {
        var running = true;

        return running;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    Random newObject = new Random();

    newObject.Name = "Johnny";

    var result = newObject.IsRunning();
}
```

which all exists in the same .cs file in the same namespace. Any time I've created a new project before I've never had to set up anything to use dot notation to access member attributes or methods, but this is saying that I can't use newObject. ANYTHING, and also that "var" is not valid for a keyword. It's a windows forms application like I normally use, but I'm drawing blanks here as why I can't do all these things that I normally use many times in my other programs. What am I missing here?

Comment: However, it WILL accept 
Random newObject = new Random()
{
   Name = "Johnny"
};

Comment: You have to have your code inside a method or a function.  Probably best inside the constructor.

Comment: Using Random and Main causing ambiguity in this specific instance since Random is part of the framework and there probably is a Main in the namespace for an exe ?  The code clearly is looking at the local file for the object resolutions however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use var or assign values to some other object within a class member definition.

You code in `public class Main` is not within a method.
I guess what you were trying to do is writing a Console app and that needs a

```
public static void Main()
```

method

so change your class to e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random newObject = new Random();

        newObject.Name = "Johnny";

        var result = newObject.IsRunning();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to write code directly within the class declaration. A class declaration can only directly contain member declarations. It can't contain arbitrary statements such as `newObject.Name = "Johnny"` nor can it use `var`, which is only applicable to *local* variables. If you put the code in a method, it should be absolutely fine. For example:

```
public class Main
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Random newObject = new Random();
        newObject.Name = "Johnny";
        var result = newObject.IsRunning();
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend against naming your own class `Random` given that that's also the name of a class within the `System` namespace.

Comment: Your answers always contain something for which I **have** to upvote it. For ex, in this answer - *naming your own class Random given that that's also the name of a class within the System namespace.*